# How to open video/mp4 with php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to read mp4 files with PHP, my initial code was

```
 $file = 'https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/onlytestes/video.mp4';
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
readfile($file);
```

But that way I couldn't use the length bar of the video, skip or even go back, until the video is 100% loaded.
Of course when I read the file directly (video.mp4) everything is fine.
I solved this problem with the following code:

```
$request = 'video.mp4';
$file = $request;
$fp = @fopen($file, 'rb');
$size   = filesize($file); // File size
$length = $size;           // Content length
$start  = 0;               // Start byte
$end    = $size - 1;       // End byte
header('Content-type: video/mp4');
header("Accept-Ranges: 0-$length");
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'])) {
    $c_start = $start;
    $c_end   = $end;
    list(, $range) = explode('=', $_SERVER['HTTP_RANGE'], 2);
    if (strpos($range, ',') !== false) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    if ($range == '-') {
        $c_start = $size - substr($range, 1);
    }else{
        $range  = explode('-', $range);
        $c_start = $range[0];
        $c_end   = (isset($range[1]) && is_numeric($range[1])) ? $range[1] : $size;
    }
    $c_end = ($c_end > $end) ? $end : $c_end;
    if ($c_start > $c_end || $c_start > $size - 1 || $c_end >= $size) {
        header('HTTP/1.1 416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable');
        header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
        exit;
    }
    $start  = $c_start;
    $end    = $c_end;
    $length = $end - $start + 1;
    fseek($fp, $start);
    header('HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content');
}
header("Content-Range: bytes $start-$end/$size");
header("Content-Length: ".$length);
$buffer = 1024 * 8;
while(!feof($fp) && ($p = ftell($fp)) <= $end) {
    if ($p + $buffer > $end) {
        $buffer = $end - $p + 1;
    }
    set_time_limit(0);
    echo fread($fp, $buffer);
    flush();
}
fclose($fp);
exit();
```

But it only works with local files, I think HTTP_RANGE does not work, it returns the following error in the console
''Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)''

I need to read Amazon S3 videos, for example: [video here](https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/onlytestes/video.mp4)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you read Document Manual Amazon SDK..?

(1) [Download](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforphp/) latest stable version of SDK

(2) Extract the .zip file & place in wamp/www folder

(3) Rename config-sample.inc.php file to config.inc.php

(4) Add the access key & secret key (retrieved from Amazon S3 account) into
     above file, save & exit

(5) create a sample file to display public / private objects from Amazon S3

Comment: I did everything you said, but it did not work.

How will the code in the sample file look like to display the file in amazon s3?

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: Have you register ‘streamWrapper’ with your s3 client ?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/fuob6y yes, but how do I return reading the video in the browser? I already tried to echo in $contents = file_get_contents("s3://{$bucket}/{$key}") but it does not work

Comment: passing file path to class’s constructor, use “s3://{bucket}/{key}” format as file string. This little bit coding "open_stream": private function open()
    {
        // Create a stream context to allow seeking
        $context = stream_context_create(array(
            's3' => array(
                'seekable' => true
            )
        ));
        if (!($this->stream = fopen($this->path, 'rb', false, $context))) {
            die('Could not open stream for reading');
        }
        
    }

Comment: thank you Yusnur Hidayah

But I still have problems,

Opening the file by the SDK / StreamWrapper, it takes about 18 seconds for the video to start, see

http://192.241.159.176/file.php

This way it is impossible to make available to users

Usually opens in 1 or 2 seconds, see

https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/onlytestes/video.mp4

Answer (score 0):

thank you Yusnur Hidayah

But I still have problems,

Opening the file by the SDK / StreamWrapper, it takes about 18 seconds for the video to start, see

http://192.241.159.176/file.php

This way it is impossible to make available to users

Usually opens in 1 or 2 seconds, see

https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/onlytestes/video.mp4